# Why is my disk usage 100% on startup on a Lenovo Notebook E540 running Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit?

Tags: windows-8.1, performance, lenovo-laptop

I have a [Lenovo Notebook E540](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/edge-series/e540/), with Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit 
and with each startup the system will be almost stopped for more than 15 mins.

When I checked the task manager, I found out that my disk usage is 100% (!!) and there is nothing that I can see on the list that is taking hardly any space.

I searched everywhere, tried to  stop the SuperFetch service or changing the page file configuration and nothing worked.

It’s really frustrating and I have no clue what the problem might be.

Comment: capture a boot trace (http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE) and share it. Here I can see the DISK activity and which process causes it.

Comment: How much RAM? At startup, besides superfetch, there are a number of things thay may happed, like windows checking for updates, antivirus (if any) checking for updates, antivirus (if configured) doing a quick scan

Answer (score 0):

(The problem here could be any of literally dozens of programs, so this answer will not be conclusive, but it should tell you how to find out what the problem is.)

That "disk usage" counter does not refer to how full the disk is, it's how busy it is. 100% busy for 15 minutes is definitely excessive.

From Task Manager's Performance tab, click "Open Resource Monitor". In that display, click the "Disk" tab. This should show you which processes are hitting the disk, and which files are being accessed. This should tell you what programs are the culprits.

Since this is clearly something that is happening at startup time, you might use the "Autoruns" tool from sysinternals.com to investigate everything that is set to start when you boot, or when you log in.

An interesting diagnostic step for these problems is to create another user account and see if the same problem happens there. If it doesn't, the issue is something that is set to start up when *you* log in (the per-user settings). Autoruns will distinguish between per-user and system-wide startup programs.

Answer (score 0):

More on the previous answer try doing a benchmark on your HDD and see the results, this could tell you if you're HDD is running slow and is defective.

Furthermore, if you can't figure out what's causing the issue you can always reinstall Windows and see how that works out for you. If it's not the HDD defective, you probably got some kind of bloatware.